# calling a class/table method in WinSQL

Tags: intersystems-cache

new to Cache so please forgive me,

I'm trying to call a class/table method in WinSQL. Basically trying to go select table_methodname() but it says it's not finding the stored function.

In Cache SQL there seems to be either a result set stored procedure which acts like a normal T-SQL stored proc or a class/table method (stored function) that acts like a function.. those are the ones I'm having trouble calling in WinSQL..

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call a ClassMethod from SQL, you must mark the ClassMethod with the [SqlProc] modifier.

```
ClassMethod MyMethod() As %Integer [SqlProc]
{
...
}
```

Then, you can call it with

```
SELECT MySchema.MyClass_MyMethod()
```

Documentation is here:

http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20141/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=ROBJ_method_sqlproc